# Return array elements to a variable length array in parameter

Tags: ruby, arrays, recursion

I have a ruby function with the following function header `def get_value( default, *args )`, and I'm using recursion in my function body, and I want to pass the args array without the first element, what I have used is `get_value(default, args.slice(1, args.length))`, however, after using a debugger, I found that the args in the recursed function was an array of arrays, and the inner arrays contained my elements. So if my main array was `[:files, :mode]` the recursed array would be `[[:mode]]`. How can I make it that is becomes `[:mode]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `get_value` with the splat operator:

```
get_value(default, *args.slice(1, args.length))
```

or with additional brevity

```
get_value(default, *args[1..-1])
```

Comment: That's another question => http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/